# Отказывается работать якорная ссылка

Tags: html, html5

Изучаю HTML, разбираюсь с якорными ссылками. Пытаюсь создать свою ссылку, но она почему-то не срабатывает.

Вот код:

```
<body>
    <p id="#a1;">////////////////////////////</p>
    <a id="#yakor">Это якорь </a>
    <pre> 
    georgiang
    gg
    georgiang
    georgiang

    georgiang
    georgiang
    georgiang

    georgiang
    georgiang
    georgiang

    g  
    </pre>
    <a href="#yakor">Begin</a>

    </body>
```

Где ошибся?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/sz9btms6/ - удалите # для id

Answer (score 6):

У вас что-то с кодом. Не видно начала.
Пример вот: http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/yakorya

```
<a name="some"></a>
...
<a href="#some></a>
```

Адрес в строке должен меняться. Если это происходит - ссылка работает.

Comment: Правильно, товарищ прописал якорю `id`, вместо `name`,

Answer (score 1):

Для id или name не должно быть #

```
<p id="anchor"></p>
...
<a href="#anchor"></a>
```